# Add computed column using subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery, sql-server-2000, calculated-columns

In SQL Server 2000, I want to add a computed column which basically is `MAX(column1)`.

Of course I get an error because subqueries are not allowed.

What I basically try to do is to get the `max(dateandtime)` of a number of tables of my database.

However when I run my code it takes too long because it's a very old and badly designed database with no keys and indexes.

So, I believe that by adding a new computed column which is the `max(datetime)`, I will do my query much much faster because I will query

```
(SELECT TOP 1 newcomputedcolumn FROM Mytable)
```

and I will not have to do

```
(SELECT TOP 1 dateandtime FROM Mytable 
 ORDER BY dateandtime DESC)
```

or

```
(SELECT MAX(dateandtime) FROM Mytable)
```

which takes too long.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there an **index** on your `dateandtime` column? That would most defnitely speed up any lookups (and `MAX()` operations) quite a bit! Calculating something like this and storing it isn't a very clever idea......

Comment: Yes the DB is ancient but its not up to me to upgrate it. Unfortunatelly there are no indexes and also i am not very familiar with databases. However i was told to do the above queries an i try to find a solution.

Comment: Add an index - seriously - right now. `CREATE INDEX ix_dateandtime ON dbo.YourTableName(dateandtime);` - that should speed things up quite a bit already

Comment: ok i will test this at first. i have 150 tables and now the query takes at least 5 minutes to respond. the desired is to respond under 5 seconds.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: THis seems a bad idea all round, this max(vlue) is only going to change when the data changes and unless I misunderstand your question, is the same value for al rows, so store it separately and update it using a trigger. Ideally then use it in a view, you might be able to return it in a computed column with a scalar function - but SQL Server 2000... no idea.

Comment: *"In SQL Server 2000"* **Why** are you *still* using this version? It's been out of support for at *least* a decade. It is long past time to get to a supported version; which (without mixing my words) is going to be an absolute arse ache to get onto now. You are going to need to *at least* migrate to and from the **completely** unsupported SQL Server 2008 to get the the supported SQL Server 2017. Honestly, sort out your version issues first, that is by far your priority.

Comment: Also, as mentioned, this should be on a `VIEW`, not a computed column. This is easily served by a windowed aggregate function, which all **supported** versions of SQL Server support.